# How to inject $location into a click event handler defined in a config function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I am amending some code that is a plugin to an AngularJS analytics framework. In the plugin, I would like access to the `$location`object within what is essentially a `$routeChangeSuccess` handler. The event handler is defined in a config function, but when the code actually executes, my understanding is that $location should be available.

The following doesn't work:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['angulartics'])
.config(['$analyticsProvider','$injector', function ($analyticsProvider, $injector) {
  $analyticsProvider.registerPageTrack(function (path) {
    // The following runs on $routeChangeSuccess
    $injector.invoke(['$location',function($location) {
      try {
          analytics.page({
            path: path,
            url: $location.absUrl()
          });
      } catch (e) {
          if (!(e instanceof ReferenceError)) {
              throw e;
          }
      }
    }]);
  });

  $analyticsProvider.registerEventTrack(function (action, properties) {
    try {
      analytics.track(action, properties);
    } catch (e) {
        if (!(e instanceof ReferenceError)) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
  });
}]);
})(angular);
```

In this case, the `$injector` cannot find the `$location` service. In digging a little further, I found out that is because the injector I have is actually the [provider injector](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d3b1f502e3099d91042a1827a006ad112ea67d36/src/auto/injector.js#L624) (because that is what is given to me by the `config` function) and not the [instance injector](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d3b1f502e3099d91042a1827a006ad112ea67d36/src/auto/injector.js#L629) (which has `$location`).

Is there any way for me to get the instance injector, rather than the provider injector? I am pretty sure that the instance injector is fully available when the code actually runs. If I'm wrong on that, then I'd like to know too! Thanks!

Comment: well you can do it like this of course `var $injector = angular.element(document.documentElement).injector(); var $location = $injector.get('$location');`.. But it's not nice.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that is not very elegant. What are the potentials downsides of this approach? I think it might be hard to unit test... Anything else?

Comment: I had this same issue when trying to use `$location` for analytics. I ended up using `$window` instead and grabbing the url with `$window.location.pathname`.